# Using jqtransform for cfselect binding

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, jqtransform

I am using jqtransform throughout my ColdFusion site for styling form fields. One of my pages uses some CFSELECT tags which bind to a CFC to get their data. However, because jqtransform works before my binding does, I do not see anything in the drop-down. I understand the reasons for this, but I guess what I need to do is find a way of telling jqtransform to run again AFTER the binding has refreshed?

I have looked at similar topics regarding jqtransform with dynamic data, but none that actually work. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You could just use jquery to get your related select data instead of farting around with cfform gotchas

Comment: The CFCs that my CFSELECTS bind to contain lots of queries and evaluations. Not sure how jQuery would handle that? If that's my only option, then I'll do some research...

Comment: binding cfselect to another cfselect is mostly javascript that CF creates. your cfc would run the same if you hit it from the browser or from jquery.  what is the CFC output, text, json, xml?

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20649876/3080438

Modify the pligin as the article.
After your binding,  you re-jqTransform the select box